# Why does Swift 3 treat NSString differently for OSX vs iOS build?

Tags: ios, macos, nsstring, swift3

I have a class that is shared by iOS and OSX. After upgrading to Swift 3, the following line of code:

```
let textSize = ("999" as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName:labelFont!])
```

...causes the following error for an iOS build:

*Incorrect argument label in call (have 'withAttributes:', expected 'attributes:').*

Fixed as follows:

```
let textSize = ("999" as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:labelFont!])
```

But then the OSX build has the error:

*Incorrect argument label in call (have 'attributes:', expected 'withAttributes:')*

Why is NSString treated differently for iOS vs OSX build?

(I have worked around this using extensions. All other shared code has successfully converted to Swift 3.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString` sizing is treated differently mostly due to the methods of measurement each use... (`NSSize` v `CGSize`):

**OS X:**

```
extension NSString {

    @available(OSX 10.0, *)
    open func size(withAttributes attrs: [String : Any]? = nil) -> NSSize
        ...
}
```

**iOS:**

```
extension NSString {

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    open func size(attributes attrs: [String : Any]? = nil) -> CGSize
          ...
}
```

Other than OS X using `NSSize`, and iOS using `CGSize` they have quite similar "size" methods apart from the former using `AppKit` and the latter using `UIKit`.